# I want to store child nodes on xml file in mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml, google-maps

I am working on google maps api and i want to store places data in my sql server, i am getting data in xml file and from the below code i can store following data (name,place_id,visinity) but apart form it i want to store (lat,lng) as well..

```
$url ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location=22.722822,75.887055&radius=2000&type=pharmacy&keyword=medical&key=*************************";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);    foreach ($xml -> result as $row) {      
    $name = $row -> name;
    $place_id= $row -> place_id;
    $vicinity= $row -> vicinity;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO google_coordinate (name,address,place_id) VALUES ('$name','$vicinity','$place_id')";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$result){
        echo 'error';
    }else{
        echo "success";
    }
}
```

Comment: google maps api

Comment: i havent created xml..i am getting it from google maps places by searching  with the place id...plz refer the below link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply follow the data structure like this

```
foreach ($xml->result as $row) {

    $name       = $row->name;
    $place_id   = $row->place_id;
    $vicinity   = $row->vicinity;
    $lat        = $row->geometry->location->lat;
    $lon        = $row->geometry->location->lon;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO google_coordinate 
                    (name,address,place_id,lat,lon) 
            VALUES ('$name','$vicinity','$place_id', '$lat', '$lon')";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$result){
        echo 'error';
    }else{
        echo "success";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this

```
$lat = $row->geometry->location->lat;
$lng = $row->geometry->location->lng;

$sql = "INSERT INTO google_coordinate (name, address, lat, lng, place_id) VALUES ('$name', '$vicinity', '$lat', '$lng', '$place_id')";
```